# iOS Devtools.Core Framework pbxcp missing in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, devtools

I downloaded the Doomclassic Source Code and wanted to have a look at it. First I wanted to compile it to see if it actually works. So I followed the instructions and copied the .wad files into the base folder, openend the project and hit compile. Aside from the over 300 warnings and the missing files (mostly Images, which I mostly fixed) I have a strange error during teh compile phase and google is no help at all.

It says:

> /Users/tobias/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Doom-egfadrxunamfwjdsdaylawcyppkc/Build/Intermediates/Doom.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Doom.build/Script-435F41A90F532CA300887552.sh: line 3: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp: No such file or directory

When I check my Xcode.app the only framework in the PrivateFrameworks folder is IDEBundleInjection.framework

I also had a look at the script:

> ## !/bin/sh -x
>
> PBXCP=${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp
> ${PBXCP} -exclude .svn "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../base" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"

So it seems that I need this framework - but even with google I couldn't find it and I wouldn't know how to integrate it into the Xcode App? I have updated Xcode to 4.4 just now but it's still the same error.

Does anyone has any advice please?

Answer (score 3):

The pbxcp command was removed from XCode 4.4, so you'll have to find a replacement for it. See  [this mailing list thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/319936-pbxcp-vanished-in-xcode-4-4.html) to alternatives to the command.