# PBXCP: No such file or directory, in most recent xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, shell

I have been modifying this open source code with Xcode 3.0 but as soon as I updated my Xcode to 4.0+ and tryed running it it no longer worked. The first error I ran into was this

```
/Users/newperson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hellcraft-etesgjzdmfzimlgvakidckjecgij/Build    
/Intermediates/Hellcraft.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Doom.build/Script-
435F41A90F532CA300887552.sh: line 3: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Libra/PrivateFrameworks    
/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp: No such file or directory
```

I figured it had something to do with the Run Script under build phases, which is set as this:

```
/bin/sh -x

PBXCP=${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp
${PBXCP} -exclude .svn "${PROJECT_DIR}/../../base" 
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
```

But after looking online and modifying the shell script countless amount of times I have not been able to find a solution.
I found somewhere that pbxcp has been removed in the more recent versions of Xcode, but I am unable to find a suitable replacement, and am unable to incorporate that DevToolsCore into the new version of Xcode.

After finding a forum that said I should run an alternative script in order to makeup for the missing pbxcp file I tryed running this:

```
/usr/bin/tar -c -C "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" --exclude .DS_Store --exclude CVS --exclude 
.svn --exclude .git -H `cd "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" && find DevToolsCore.framework` | 
/usr/bin/tar -x -C ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}
```

I created a file called myframeworks in the project directory and added DevToolsCore.framework to it, although this fixed the missing pbxcp problem it generated another error:

```
tar: could not chdir to '/Users/newperson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hellcraft-
etesgjzdmfzimlgvakidckjecgij/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Doom.app/Frameworks'

tar: Write error
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

If anyone has any advice it would be great, I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: Check your App 'Target's-> Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources' once if there is any files that is missing or in Red, Remove/Add them and try compiling again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would have deleted some item from your Xcode.I also had this PBXc error, all i did was i added the same file again and got rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

See the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820995/ios-devtools-core-framework-pbxcp-missing-in-xcode) and [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/319936-pbxcp-vanished-in-xcode-4-4.html). The thread states that `pbxcp` got removed in Xcode 4.4 and as it was an Xcode-internal tool there is no official replacement, but the thread does offer a replacement if you scroll down using `tar` and `find`.

Comment: I also found that thread and tried modifying the tar/find statements in it. I created a file in my project directory called myframeworks and added a devtoolscore file i found online. then I ran this script:
/usr/bin/tar -c -C "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" --exclude .DS_Store --exclude CVS --exclude .svn --exclude .git -H `cd "${PROJECT_DIR}/myframeworks" && find DevToolsCore.framework` | /usr/bin/tar -x -C ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}

It ran the script for awhile but then ran into this error:

tar: could not chdir 
tar: Write error
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Comment: please update your question with your best try at solving your problem, so readers don't have to try and understand both the problem above, plus this hard to read addition here. Good luck.